# Adobe Fireworks - Rotating vector shape causes worse quality

Tags: vector, adobe-fireworks

I am trying to create an arrow with the vector shape tool in Adobe Fireworks. I used the rectangle tool to create a thin rounded line and when i copied and pasted another version to rotate it, I noticed that the quality is now worse than the original. [zooming in confirms this] Does anyone know how I can fix that issue? I need to rotate the line to create an arrow.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Fireworks. What happens is that the vector points are positioned differently inside the pixels after the modification. It happens on rotating and sometimes on pasting. Try snapping points to pixel after you rotate or modify your shape:

`Mainmenu > Modify > Snap to pixel`

or one of the options on the `Path panel`

`Alter paths > Snap to pixel`

`Edit points > Round Points To Pixels`

`Edit points > Round Points To Half Pixels`